# Touch event for right and left bar button items of navigationbar in ios7

Tags: button, touch, uinavigationitem, ios7.1, rightbarbuttonitem

I created left bar button item and array of 2 bar button items to the right bar button item. Here, the problem is, if I tap on area out of the left and right bar button items, the navigation occurs.How to remove this touch behaviour at the area out of the buttons?

[image]

I created left and right bar button items as shown in figure.Kindly answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the back button with the `hidesBackButton` property on the navigation item?

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

See the [UINavigationItem docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/hidesBackButton).